# SQL query - union on NOW()

Tags: mysql

I tried making a SQL query and union the result on the current time, but I cannot seem to find a neat way to solve this.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts`
UNION SELECT NOW()
```

And Sequel Pro just reports `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`.

The `accounts`table just has three columns:

- ID      (INT(32), AUTO_INC)
- CREATED (Timestamp)
- NAME    (VAR_CHAR(28))

I anticipated I'd get a response with four columns: ID, CREATED, NAME, NOW

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union means that the records from the second query will be appended to those retrieved from the first one. 
So the two tables must have the same structure for this to work. 
For example:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM tableB
```

What you want to do is

```
SELECT *, NOW() as now FROM `accounts`
```

This will retrieve all the records from the accounts table and will add the timestamp to all the rows on a column named "now" (this is just an alias so use whatever you like).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT *,now() as now FROM `accounts`
```